# JavaFX & Generics - observing a property of Node which is an ObservableValue

Tags: java, generics, javafx

Given a property of a JavaFX Node declared as:

```
public final ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Bounds> boundsInParentProperty
```

...which is an ObservableValue<Bounds>. And a method implemented in corresponding ChangeListener<Bounds>:

```
public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Bounds> observedValue, Bounds oldvalue, Bounds newvalue)
```

What is the first argument in the method for?

At first I used observedValue.getValue(), but later I was able to calculate the delta of various coordinates of Bounds from just the second and third argument (newvalue - oldvalue). The type of argument is known (Bounds), so it's not like a key-value scheme. I'm highly distrustful of what I don't understand, so what is this 'observedValue' and should I use it?

EDIT: After the comments I understand it's used for determining which ObservableValue (if multiple) is the source of the event. Let's say I want to have a Line drawn between two draggable Nodes on screen, and I want to track the Bounds of both this way. How to determine which Node is the source of change event (get its reference)?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you subscribe your listener to multiple variables change, and you may be interested which one of them had changed. It's quite popular trick in Observer implementation.

Comment: i.e. `observedValue` is a reference to the property that changed.

Comment: Or to be more specific: As `observedValue` will be passed in your `boundsInParentProperty`, because it is the instance of ObservableValue that has triggered the change.